# How to store hundreds of small pictures in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch

In my iOS app, I need to cache hundreds of small pictures (50x50) in iPhone. I'm looking for the right way to store them. Several ideas come to my mind:

1. Store them with Core Data.
2. Store them in file system. I keep
   hundreds of paths to refer them
   later.
3. Store all of them as a big file. But
   it's difficult to change or remove
   one of the picture...
4. Don't cache them at all, read them
   from web every-time I need them
   instead.

Do you have any good idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thinks either coredata, or sqlite3 is a good idea, i used sqlite3 to do this, but only around 200 similar images, but for more images, using coredata is definitely faster

Comment: Thanks, all the documents suggest against storing images in sqlite, what do you think of your solution? Any drawbacks?

Comment: Yes, but for small amount, there isn't so much difference, it is fast and convenient, for me, I did't see any drawbacks, and there is no memory issues either.

Answer (score 1):

what I'm doing is,

make on sqlite table with two columns
URL and filename.
After I get image from Web, store URL and file name in table, and store image in file.

well I've done in many apps like this. (May someone has better way)

Comment: Thanks. But I don't think storing hundreds of small files a good idea.

Comment: yes, you are right. totally agree with you. but there are two options. Either you save on files or in database. Saving on database will not be problem in your case, if you are using 50X50 sized images, isnot it? saving on a large file is not good idea I guess

Answer (score 0):

I would use Core Data, as it would require minimal amount of work from your side, and you will be using Apple's framework, so it will probably be more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a lookt at [ZSAssetManager](https://github.com/ZarraStudios/ZDS_Shared), it uses the file system to cache images, and does much more!